# Login to Synology via Quickconnect ID via webapi not working

Tags: java, android, synology

When I use this link in PC browser :
"http://QuickconnectID.quickconnect.to/webapi/entry.cgi?api=SYNO.API.Auth&version=6&method=login&account=&passwd=&session=FileStation&format=sid"
Result will be:

```
{"data":{"did":"","is_portal_port":false,"sid":"FnNj2gZlk1JKCuvRgnPxmobytzHr-gsOgfk0sGIc1LisvEF-20VV4EDD6BMndvCGnt2vT1cGQobg"},"success":true}
```

What is correct te get session id for work with Synology.But when I use code to login via android app:

```
String strurl = "http://QuickconnectID.quickconnect.to/webapi/entry.cgi?api=SYNO.API.Auth&version=6&method=login&account=<ACCOUNT>&passwd=<PASSWORD>&session=FileStation&format=sid"

String s  = fetchHttpList(strurl);

private static URL createUrl(String stringUrl) {
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(stringUrl);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Problem building the URL ", e);
        }
        return url;
    }

public static String fetchHttpList(String requestUrl) {
        URL url = createUrl(requestUrl);
        String jsonResponse = null;
        try {

            jsonResponse = makeHttpRequest(url,"GET");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Problem making the HTTP request.", e);
        }
        return jsonResponse;
    }

private static String makeHttpRequest(URL url,String method) throws IOException {
        String jsonResponse = "";
        if (url == null) {
            return jsonResponse;
        }
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try {

            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod(method); //change in v16
            urlConnection.connect();
            if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                jsonResponse = readFromStream(inputStream);
            } else {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error response code: " + urlConnection.getResponseCode());
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, url.toString());
            }
        } catch(ConnectException e){
            throw e;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Problem retrieving the JSON results.", e);
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            if (inputStream != null) {
                inputStream.close();
            }
        }
        return jsonResponse;

    }
```

Result of s will be temporary PAGE WITH connecting:

```
<!doctype html> <html> <head> <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-131382946-3">**strong text**  etc...

<br>
```

Synology uses some redirection of web login pages. After enter link in browser 
http://somename.quickconnect.to 
final link after redirection will be:
http://somename.direct.quickconnect.to:5001
Can you help me with this issue to get JSON like from PC Browser?

Comment: Just follow the redirect instructions provided by HTTP headers? Some HTTP clients do follow these on their own, but not all of them.

Comment: Yes it is right, I found some on :[GITHUB](https://github.com/wujingwe/quickconnect-interceptor) .Into HTTP requests must be added interceptor to get External IP and port to get final external link. I would not come to this speciality by myself. Thank you